# Switch Case and For Loop C++

Tags: c++, loops, switch-statement

Hello I have this code and I cant seem to get it to work. The loop loops for three times and then the addCourse is suppose to add all three selections. The problem is the addCourse function only adds the last bit for all three selections. Example :

If I select 1 2 3 then it is suppose to give out:

1. Maths
2. Quantum
3. Reality

Instead it gives out:

1. Reality
2. Reality
3. Reality

(All three is the case 3 which is selected last)

How do I sort this problem. Thank you. Below is the code.

```
for(int p = 0; p < 3; p++)
{
    cout << "Please select a course:" <<endl;
    cout<<"1. Maths\n";
    cout<<"2. Quantum\n";
    cout<<"3. Reality\n";
    cin >> coursepick;
    switch (coursepick)
    {
    case 1: course= "Maths";
    case 2: course= "Quantum";
    case 3: course= "Reality";
    default: break;
    }
    cout << "Please insert the course mark:" <<endl;
    cin >> mark;
    cin.ignore();
    phys[0]->addCourse(course,mark);
}
```

Comment: If this question is resolved, you should accept the appropriate answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
switch (coursepick)
{
case 1: course= "Maths"; break;
case 2: course= "Quantum"; break;
case 3: course= "Reality"; break;
default: break;
}
```

if you don't break at the end of each case, it just continue with the next, and the next, and then until case 3 and break on default.

Comment: Thanks. Work perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, `case` statements automatically move on to the next. You must insert `break` after each `case`.

```
switch (coursepick)
{
    case 1: course= "Maths"; break;
    case 2: course= "Quantum"; break;
    case 3: course= "Reality"; break;
    default: break;
}
```

Comment: Why does this happen? Never made too much sense to me.

Comment: Thanks. Work perfectly

Comment: @Ben: because C was heavily influenced by Fortran, which had [computed GOTOs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computed_GOTO#Computed_GOTO) (or branch tables), which is pretty much what a `switch`-`case` block is.

Answer (score 1):

In your `switch` statement you need a `break` statement in each `case`.  Without a `break` statement C will fall to the next case.  You case statement is equivalent to:

```
course= "Maths";
course= "Quantum";
course= "Reality";
```

Instead it needs to be:

```
switch (coursepick)
{
    case 1: course= "Maths"; break;
    case 2: course= "Quantum"; break;
    case 3: course= "Reality"; break;
    default: break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the other posts, you need to end each case with the keyword "break;" if you don't want it to trickle down into the next case.

```
switch (coursepick)
{
    case 1: course= "Maths"; break;
    case 2: course= "Quantum"; break;
    case 3: course= "Reality"; break;
    default: break;
}
```

Switch statements have this behavior because sometimes you *want* it to filter through multiple cases. This saves you from having to duplicate code when multiple cases have the same result. The following example shows the equivalent of if case 'a' OR case 'A', do this. If case 'b' OR 'B', do this.

```
switch (input)
{
    case 'a':
    case 'A': text = "Letter A"; break;

    case 'b':
    case 'B': text = "Letter B"; break;

    default: text = "Not A or B"; break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dude Can you add Break tag for all the case statements. It Should be like this

```
switch (coursepick)
    {
    case 1: course= "Maths";
            break;
    case 2: course= "Quantum";
            break;
    case 3: course= "Reality";
            break;
    default: break;
    }
```

If you don't mention it will be through all the cases and finally in case three course will be over written by Reality.

So break is necessary for case statements

Answer (score 0):

As it was already said you have to use `break` for any case label.

```
switch (coursepick)
{
case 1: course= "Maths"; break;
case 2: course= "Quantum"; break;
case 3: course= "Reality"; break;
default: break; 
}
```

But in any case the code is invalid bacause if the user will enter a number outside the acceptable range variable course will not be assigned. However you will use this unassigned variable in statement

```
phys[0]->addCourse(course,mark);
```

Also it is not clear why the variable is defined outside the loop.

I would write the loop the following way

```
enum { Maths = 1, Quantum, Reality };

for ( int p = 0; p < 3; p++ )
{
    do
    {
        cout << "\nPlease select a course:" <<endl;
        cout<<"1. Maths\n";
        cout<<"2. Quantum\n";
        cout<<"3. Reality\n";

        cin >> coursepick;

        if ( !( Maths <= coursepick && coursepick <= Reality ) )
        {
            cout << "Error. Invalid input. Please repeat" << std::endl;
        }
    } while ( !( Maths <= coursepick && coursepick <= Reality ) ); 

    switch (coursepick)
    {
        case Maths: course= "Maths"; break;
        case Quantum: course= "Quantum"; break;
        case Reality: course= "Reality"; break;
        default: abort();
    }

    cout << "Please insert the course mark:" << endl;
    cin >> mark;
    cin.ignore();
    phys[0]->addCourse( course, mark );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the more elegant way of writing.